# Class Attribute Variable is not updating

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, tkinter

I am creating a game where the player is a ship that has to dodge meteors that fall. I have 2 classes, the ship and the meteors. The meteors "fall" by having their canvas objects moved down their y axis and their y coordinates are subtracted by the number as the move function. I have an if statement that detects whether the meteors have fallen passed the border of the canvas, and it deletes those meteors, and creates new meteors at the top of the screen, thus making it seem that there are multiple meteors that are falling. The ship class has a similar function that detects if the ship has gone passed the sides of the canvas, which triggers the death function. I have a function in the meteor class that detects whether it is overlapping, with the help from Sneaky Turtle's answer. Now, it's almost finished, I just have one problem. After 3 "rounds" the meteors should get faster. How I implemented this was by having an if statement that checks if a variable is over 3. If not, the variable adds 1. When it reaches 3, it resets and adds (speed amount) to the speed attribute of the meteor,which is used when it moves. the problem is it only works on the first "wave" after that, the speed attribute stays the same. All the sound functions are commented off so that I don't have to upload the files.
Code:

```
from random import *
from tkinter import *
from time import *
print('''****Meteor Run****
Don't let the meteors hit you!
     A-Left D-Right ''')
sleep(1.25)
#from game_sounds import*
root=Tk()
c = Canvas(width=800,height=600,bg="#37061a")
c.pack()
m1=0
m2=0
m3=0
m4=0
m5=0
m6=0
m7=0
m8=0
direction=0
speed=0
score = 0
cont=True
class ship:
    def __init__(self,x1,y1,x2,y2):
        self.x1=x1
        self.y1=y1
        self.x2=x2
        self.y2=y2
        self.hitbox3=387.5 + x1
        self.shape=c.create_polygon(353+x1,380+y1,387.5+x1,310+y1,
                                    420+x1,380+y1,fill="Blue")
    def move(self):
     global direction
     if direction=="L":
      self.x1 = self.x1-10
      self.hitbox3 = self.hitbox3-10
      c.move(self.shape,-10,0)
      sleep(0.001)
      root.update()
     if direction=="R":
      self.x1 = self.x1+10
      self.hitbox3 = self.hitbox3+10
      c.move(self.shape,10,0)
      root.update()
      self.test_lost_in_space()
      sleep(0.001)
    def death(self):
     root.destroy()
     print("You Lost!")
     print("Score:",score)
#     death_sound()

    def test_lost_in_space(self):
        if self.hitbox3<=0:
            self.death()
        if self.hitbox3 >=800:
            self.death()
    def ship_explode(self):
        overlap = c.find_overlapping(353+self.x1,380+self.y1,420+self.x1,310+self.y1)
        if overlap != (self.shape,):
         self.death()
class meteor:
 def __init__(self,x1,y1):
     self.x1=x1
     self.y1=y1
     self.hitbox=89+x1
     self.speed=.75
     self.shape =c.create_polygon(1+x1,50+y1,34+x1,23+y1,67+x1,23+y1,
                                  89+x1,57+y1,64+x1,71+y1,27+x1,71+y1,fill="brown")
 def meteor_return(self):
     global m1
     global m2
     global m3
     global m4
     global m5
     global m6
     global m7
     global m8
     global speed
     global score
     if self.y1 >=600:
      c.delete(self)
      m1=meteor(randrange(0,700),randrange(6,12))
      m2=meteor(randrange(0,700),randrange(6,12))
      m3=meteor(randrange(0,700),randrange(6,12))
      m4=meteor(randrange(0,700),randrange(6,12))
      m5=meteor(randrange(0,700),randrange(6,12))
      m6=meteor(randrange(0,700),randrange(6,12))
      m7=meteor(randrange(0,700),randrange(6,12))
      m8=meteor(randrange(0,700),randrange(6,12))
      if speed!=3:
         speed=speed +1
         score = score + 1
 #        lvl_up()
      if speed==3: 
        speed=0
        self.speed= self.speed + .5
        print(self.speed)
        score = score + 5
  #      lvl_up_2()
 def meteor_fall(self):
     global speed
     self.y1 = self.y1 + self.speed
     c.move(self.shape,0,self.speed)
     root.update()
     self.meteor_return()
  #   ship1.ship_explode()
def ship_move(event):
    global direction
    if event.keysym=="a":
     direction="L"
     ship1.move()
    if event.keysym=="d":
     direction="R"
     ship1.move()
ship1 =ship(0,0,0,0)
m1=meteor(randrange(0,200),randrange(6,12))
m2=meteor(randrange(200,400),randrange(6,12))
m3 =meteor(randrange(400,600),randrange(6,12))
m4=meteor(randrange(600,800),randrange(6,12))
m5 =meteor(randrange(400,600),randrange(6,12))
m6=meteor(randrange(600,800),randrange(6,12))
m7 =meteor(randrange(400,600),randrange(6,12))
m8=meteor(randrange(600,800),randrange(6,12))
c.bind_all("<KeyPress-a>",ship_move)
c.bind_all("<KeyPress-d>",ship_move)
while cont ==True:
    m1.meteor_fall()
    m2.meteor_fall()
    m3.meteor_fall()
    m4.meteor_fall()
    m5.meteor_fall()
    m6.meteor_fall()
    m7.meteor_fall()
    m8.meteor_fall()
c.bind_all("<KeyPress-a>",ship_move)
c.bind_all("<KeyPress-d>",ship_move)
ship1.death()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing the x and y coordinates of each meteor and seeing whether they are within the bounds of the ships co-ordinates, I would use `find_overlapping` to detect what actually overlaps the Ship.

If you have nothing on your canvas except the meteors and ship, you could implement something like:

```
ship_coords = c.coords(self.shape)
overlap = c.find_overlapping(*ship_coords)
if overlap != (self.shape, ):
    #Code to run when the meteors collide with the ship.
    ...
```

Where `(self.shape, )` is the tuple returned from the coordinates you pass to `find_overlapping`. I recommend reading documentation on the Tkinter canvas, it seems like you have just started learning! Hopefully this helps for the moment however.

If you need to specifically detect what items are overlapping with your ship, then there are plenty of other questions and answers on Stack Overflow about `find_overlapping`.

Comment: TypeError: find_overlapping() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'y1', 'x2', and 'y2'

Comment: SOLVED: Just replaced ship_coords with the coords.